# How do you install the packages your python setup.py needs in development mode using conda?

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

## How do you install the packages your python setup.py needs in development mode using conda if they are not installed automatically with conda develop .?

I have a python setup.py with these contents:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='automl', #project name
    version='0.1.0',
    description='AutoML',
    #url
    author='Charlie Parker',
    author_email='me@gmail.edu',
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['torch','numpy','scikit-learn','scipy','matplotlib','pyyml','torchviz','tensorboard',
    'graphviz','torchvision','matplotlib','dill']
)

#install_requires=['numpy>=1.11.0']
```

when I do:

```
conda develop .
```

it correctly installed my library in editable mode with coda as shown by printing the `sys.path` in python:

```
python -c "import sys; [print(p) for p in sys.path]"

/Users/ME/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python37.zip
/Users/ME/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7
/Users/ME/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/Users/ME/miniconda3/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/Users/ME/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj
/Users/ME/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-project
```

BUT it did not install all of the remaining packages that I need. So my questions are:

1. Why did it not install it
2. How do I install them with conda so that it works in my editable mode if I already specified what they are in my `setup.py`?

Comment: I think you will have to install those by hand before doing `conda develop`. Setup.py lists pypi packages not conda-packages so my guess is they are not even trying to parse the install_requires variable. If you are happy to have pip installed packages, you can of course go with `pip install -e`

Comment: @cel I am scared/concerned of mixing `pip` and `conda` though I have to admit I am ignorant of the risks (if any). Are there any risks of doing `pip install -e .` **AND** also `conda develop .`?

Comment: an alternative is to have a for loop that runs the conda install for me. Perhaps I can load the file in python, parse the line I need and then run from python the shell command I need `conda install pkg[i]` or something like that, though it sounds quite a bit of work for something so simple.

Comment: I would probably not try parsing the setup.py but instead provide an additional conda environment file.

Comment: @cel not to be ungrateful for your suggestion, but It's so annoying to have to manage not 2 config files. Makes me feel something went wrong.

Comment: @cel Unfortunately, time passed before I saw these responses and I've already tried installing it manually, but if your suggestion is `pip install -e .` perhaps I will test at a later date to switch to using `pip install -e .` instead of conda or test how it behaves with `conda develop .`, which is the one I am more familiar with (I ended up having to force install  `graphviz ` with pip anyway for my script to run so I'd guess/assume using both is probably fine, though it feels weird/uncomfortable.